# R Reference Classes - should we use $initFields or $callSuper in constructor?

Tags: r, constructor, reference-class

With regard to R Reference Classes, if we override the default `$initialize()` constructor, which is considered better practice to initialize fields: `$initFields()` or `$callSuper()`?

I've considered a few pros/cons:

- If the default behaviour of `$initialize()` is changed/extended in some future version of R, `$callSuper()` will reflect those changes without having to add/rewrite code
- There's nothing stopping you from calling `$callSuper()` twice in a single `$initialize()`. Is it officially documented/well-defined what happens in such a scenario?

Comment: Could you provide a simple example?

Comment: It's a good question and it would be good to see it developed further. [tag:reference-class] subject is important but there is not much on it when compared to other R topics. Help in ?completeSubclasses` could be much more elaborate...